# Fine tuning a pre-trained network with new data

Tags: caffe

I have a pre-trained network (the prototxt definition and binary caffemodel with the weights) designed for image recognition. I got it on-line, without knowing how it was trained, on which data, and i haven't seen the solver file.
The network has 3 layers (as far as i can tell - i have 3 prototxt files).

I'm trying to add another "feature" to the network - make it recognize some pose as well.

The steps I've taken so far:
- Add another output to the last layer, similar to the outputs that were already there
- Process the image database through the first two layers, and save the output to lmdb
- create a new solver for fine-tuning
- create a train_test for fine tuning the last layer

Running "caffe train" with the solver simply crashes.
I tried figuring out more by going into python and:

```
caffe.Net(train_test_file_path)
```

I got:

```
I0703 11:10:54.095563 21756 net.cpp:294] The NetState phase (1) differed from the phase (0) specified by a rule in layer data
I0703 11:10:54.095655 21756 net.cpp:51] Initializing net from parameters:
 <train_test_file_content>

I0703 11:10:54.096817 21756 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
I0703 11:10:54.097033 21756 db_lmdb.cpp:35] Opened lmdb /home/user/yaw_db/test/lmdb/
I0703 11:10:54.097090 21756 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer data
I0703 11:10:54.097111 21756 net.cpp:380] data -> data         
I0703 11:10:54.097158 21756 net.cpp:380] data -> label
I0703 11:10:54.097657 21756 data_layer.cpp:45] output data size: 50,1,1,193536
I0703 11:10:54.097937 21756 net.cpp:122] Setting up data     
I0703 11:10:54.097960 21756 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 50 1 1 193536 (9676800)
I0703 11:10:54.097983 21756 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 50 (50)
I0703 11:10:54.097999 21756 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 38707400
I0703 11:10:54.098014 21756 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer label_data_1_split
I0703 11:10:54.098047 21756 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer label_data_1_split
I0703 11:10:54.098063 21756 net.cpp:406] label_data_1_split <- label
I0703 11:10:54.098084 21756 net.cpp:380] label_data_1_split -> label_data_1_split_0             
I0703 11:10:54.098106 21756 net.cpp:380] label_data_1_split -> label_data_1_split_1                                                                                  
I0703 11:10:54.098131 21756 net.cpp:122] Setting up label_data_1_split
I0703 11:10:54.098145 21756 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 50 (50)                                                                                                                                                
I0703 11:10:54.098163 21756 net.cpp:129] Top shape: 50 (50)
I0703 11:10:54.098176 21756 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 38707800
I0703 11:10:54.098188 21756 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1_3
I0703 11:10:54.098212 21756 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1_3
I0703 11:10:54.098227 21756 net.cpp:406] conv1_3 <- data      
I0703 11:10:54.098245 21756 net.cpp:380] conv1_3 -> conv1_3
F0703 11:10:54.098325 21756 blob.cpp:32] Check failed: shape[i] >= 0 (-1 vs. 0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***                           
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Opening the lmdb I've created and using stat() on it produced:

```
{'branch_pages': 1,
 'depth': 2,
 'entries': 12651,
 'leaf_pages': 75,
 'overflow_pages': 561233,
 'psize': 4096}
```

Searching the internet gave me a slight idea that perhaps i saved the processed images wrong.
Any further ideas?

PS. I am *very* new to caffe, neuron networks etc. so i might even be missing the simplest of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saved your intermediate features into lmdb file (`'/home/user/yaw_db/test/lmdb'`).
The data there is stored as a collection of 1x1x193,536 dimensional features. You are reading a batch of 50 each time. You can see this in your log file:

> ```
> I0703 11:10:54.097657 21756 data_layer.cpp:45] output data size: 50,1,1,193536
> ```

Now it seems like you are trying to apply a 3x3 convolution (at layer `'conv1_3'`). However, the spatial dimensions of your input blob are 1x193,536. There's not enough "height" to the input blob to allow for 3x3 convolution, this is why you get an error

> ```
> F0703 11:10:54.098325 21756 blob.cpp:32] Check failed: shape[i] >= 0 (-1 vs. 0)
> ```

Comment: Thanks. How do i know what the first layer (conv1_3) expects as input sizes? what does more "height" mean? Also, How do you know it's 3x3?